# Why do I get the error: " Specified Cast is not valid" when trying to populate my listview in xamarin.forms with a list in my viewModel?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is the code behind of the main page in my xamarin app

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
    PenStockVM<PenStock> penstocks;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        penstocks = new PenStockVM<PenStock>();
        
        //I get the error at this point saying that this cast is invalid. How to fix this?
        listView.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)penstocks;

        BindingContext = penstocks;
    }
}
```

This is my Penstock ViewModel class:

```
       class PenStockVM<Penstock>
    {
    public List<PenStock>PenStocks { get; set; }

    public PenStockVM()
    {
        PenStocks = new List<PenStock>();
        FillPenStockData();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Graph> FillGraphData()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Graph> entries = new ObservableCollection<Graph>();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            entries.Add(new Graph { Time = i, Units = random.Next(100) });
        }

        return entries;
    }

    private void FillPenStockData()
    {
        PenStock object1 = new PenStock { Id = 1, Name = "Main PenStock", Data = 
  FillGraphData(), Rotations = 100 };
        PenStocks.Add(object1);

        PenStock object2 = new PenStock { Id = 2, Name = "Weir", Data = FillGraphData(), 
 Rotations = 100 };
        PenStocks.Add(object2);

         PenStock object3 = new PenStock { Id = 3, Name = "Spillway", Data = FillGraphData(), 
Rotations = 100 };
        PenStocks.Add(object3);

        PenStock object4 = new PenStock { Id = 4, Name = "Sub PenStock 1", Data = 
FillGraphData(), Rotations = 100 };
        PenStocks.Add(object4);

        PenStock object5 = new PenStock { Id = 5, Name = "Sub PenStock 2", Data = 
FillGraphData(), Rotations = 100 };
        PenStocks.Add(object5);

        PenStock object6 = new PenStock { Id = 6, Name = "Sub PenStock 3", Data = 
FillGraphData(), Rotations = 100 };
        PenStocks.Add(object6);

    }
}
```

This is my PenStock model class:

```
      public class PenStock
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Graph> Data { get; set; }
    public int Rotations { get; set; }
 }
```

This is my other Graph model class:

```
       public class Graph: INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
   private int time;
  private int units;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public int Time
{
    get { return time; }

    set
    {
        time = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
    }
  }

  public int Units
   {
    get { return units; }

    set
    {
        units = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
    }
   }
}
```

Do I get this error because I am trying to cast a generic list and the listView only accepts non-generic collections as item source? I am new to xamarin and please help me! Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a Xamarin issue, but rather a basic C# one. `PenStockVM` isn't an `IEnumerable`, but it holds one - `PenStocks`. So what you probably meant was `listView.ItemsSource = penstocks.PenStocks`. Maybe remaining `penstocks` to `penstocksViewModel` would be more clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand the issue. You are a life saver!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would set `ItemsSource` to `PenStockVM.PenStocks`. `ItemsSource` property specifies the items to display, which are defined in a list. A `ListView` is populated with data using the `ItemsSource` property, which is of type `IEnumerable`.

```
listView.ItemsSource = penstocks.PenStocks;
```